# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Здравствуйте! Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильность пунктуации: "Это была обычная травма среди людей, занятых такой опасной работой как разрезание и перетаскивание кусков льда."

Как я понимаю, здесь не сравнение, а отождествление (их опасная работа = разрезать и перетаскивать куски льда), и запятая перед "как" не нужна. Верно ли это? Интуитивно хочется поставить здесь запятую, но не могу понять, какому правилу соответствует этот случай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом *как*, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово *так, такой, тот, столь*. Следовательно, в вашем примере запятая нужна: *Это была обычная травма среди людей, занятых такой опасной работой, как разрезание и перетаскивание кусков льда*. (подробнее см.: Розенталь Д.Э. и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ. М.: ЧеРо, 1999. §115. Сравнительный оборот)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ и ссылку на справочник!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что запятая нужна, так как есть указательное слово **такой** (опасной работой)...

Answer (score 0):

Нет, все не так. У вас в основной части есть слово "такой", поэтому впрямую сводить ни к сравнению, ни к отождествлению нельзя.

Но случай, похоже, это довольно сложный, решение зависит от смысла.
Не совсем уверен, но я бы разобрал его так.

Если имелось в виду конкретная работа по разрезанию и перетаскивания льда, т.е. конструкция "такой ... как ..." имеет смысл усиления, то "такой ... как ..." - составной союз, запятая не требуется.

Если же имеется в виду некоторый "набор" работ или любая работа, столь же опасная как разрезание и перетаскивание, то это всё-таки приравнивание. Необходимо обособление.

Comment: В моем случае, видимо, "такой... как..." имеет смысл усиления, так как речь о конкретной работе, состоящей в разрезании и перетаскивании льда, и о том, что она довольно опасна. Получается, что запятая не требуется.

Comment: Вы знаете, я не буду настаивать. Посмотрел сейчас на похожие обороты в разных источниках - почти везде обособление (т.е запятая стоит). То ли есть ещё какой-то момент, которого я не чувствую, то ли практика пережила рекомендацию считать "такой ... как" составным союзом в подобных случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится,так как есть указательное слово "такой".